# How to prevent redirect after submitting data through a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, redirect, routes, actionmailer

New to rails (programming as a whole), and I'm a little confused about routing.

I have a form in my view that takes someone's email, and then emails them once they hit submit.  It works, but after I hit submit I'm being redirected to the view for the method I'm calling in order to mail the form. I don't want to be redirected, I want to stay on the same page.  I have attempted using POST and PUT, but both redirect me. Am I using my controller incorrectly?

My controller has this method:

```
  def mail
   recipient_email = params[:email]
   itinerary_body = params[:body]
   x = ItineraryMailer.itinerary("#{recipient_email}", "#{itinerary_body}")
   x.deliver
  end
```

And here is the form from my view:

```
  <%= form_tag({controller: "bookings", action: "mail"}, method: "post") do %>
     <%= text_field_tag(:email) %>
     <%= text_field_tag(:body) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Email Me!") %>
```

My route:

```
match '/bookings', to: 'bookings#mail', via: 'post'
```

Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to call `render 'action'` at the end of your mail action to render whatever view you like.  See Section 2.2.2 in this [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't have a `redirect_to` in your `mail` action Rails isn't redirecting you anywhere. Instead, it's just trying to render that action's view directly. However, I'm guessing that isn't the view you want rendered.

So, instead of trying to prevent a redirection (which isn't happening anyway) I would suggest that you take the opposite approach: use a redirection to get to the correct view. At the end of your `mail` action do this:

```
redirect_to action: :original_action_name
```

Where `:original_action_name` is the name of the action that gave you the view you want.

You could also use the `render 'action'` suggested in a comment, but that can cause problems in some cases where the current action may not have loaded or set up everything needed by the view you want to have rendered. Of course, you could just do that loading/setup in the current action but then you are doing the same thing in two places which isn't DRY.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my post.  I have a search field on my home page.  The user, upon searching, is taken to a page of results.  The user may then select certain results and have them emailed to him.  So, currently while you are on the search results page, you can successfully send an email with selected data, but then you are redirected to a view that doesn't exist.  I want to remain on the search results page. In fact, in costs money to preform the search, so any redirection will cause the search to process again.  I simply want to eamil to send and nothing else.

Comment: @RossRobertMcKee I understood the problem, but I was trying to point out proper terminology and I guess I wasn't very clear about that. When an action is invoked in rails, such as the search action, you don't say that you get "redirected" to the search results, you just say you were shown or taken to the search results. Same applies to the mail action: you aren't being redirected to the mail view, it's just being rendered and shown to you. Since the default mail view isn't the one you want, you need to redirect to get the one you do want. The terminology is the opposite of how you're using it.

Comment: Oh, wow.  I was clearly not looking at it that way, but that makes sense.  Thank you.